# "Variable blue might not have been initialized", does that mean I need to declare blue and where?

Tags: java, class, variables, initialization, variable-declaration

I'm not 100% sure what is wrong, it just tells me that blue has not been initialized.

```
Millionaire m1 = new Millionaire(response);
//Q1
 System.out.println("What color is blue?");
   System.out.println("1. blue");
   System.out.println("2. red");
   System.out.println("3. turquoise");
   System.out.println("4. What is 'color'?");
 input.nextLine();
 String ans = input.nextLine();     
 String blue;

 if(ans == blue){
   System.out.println("correct!");
   m1.addMoney();
 }else{
 System.out.println("Lost on the first question??");
 System.exit(0);   
}
```

Comment: Well, in this case you literally never assign any value to `blue`.  Why do you think you have?

Comment: `I'm not 100% sure what is wrong,` No it's 100% correct.  Can you show us *where* you think `blue` is initialized?

Comment: I thought I did with 'String blue;', but I guess I didn't.

Comment: And don't compare String with == please, use equals instead.

Comment: More fundamentally, you seem to be confusing the name of a variable with its value.  The value of the variable 'ans' may be the string "blue".  This has no relationship to a variable that happens to have the name 'blue'.  You don't need that variable at all; you should write `ans.equals("blue")`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `blue` isn't initialised anywhere, writing

```
String blue;
```

only declares a variable and doesn't set it to anything. Therefore when you're doing your comparison

```
ans == blue
```

you're comparing `ans` to nothing, or more specifically `null`.

---

Also as @Typhon said in the comments, you shouldn't use `==` to compare the value of two objects, but for reference equality. I would take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for some more information.

Comment: I see, so initialize it  do I assign blue to something else a well? Something like 'blue = 0;' Sorry for all the questions

Comment: Exactly, otherwise what are you trying to compare?